# how to retrieve the price type from bundle product

Tags: magento

I have an order with bundles ordered.
Each bundle has several items.

How can I retrieve if the bundle has fixed price or dynamic price? (this is defined by configuration when you create a product)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$product->getPriceType()`

this will return

`Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Price::PRICE_TYPE_FIXED`

or

```
Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Price::PRICE_TYPE_DYNAMIC
```